# WPF: initial visibility and template loading

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have encountered an issue where the bindings are not properly set on one of my user controls if that control is not visible when it is initialized. I have duplicated the issue with the following dumbed-down controls:

```
public class Test3 : Control
    {
        static Test3()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Test3), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Test3)));
        }

        public string Test
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(string), 
            typeof(Test3), new UIPropertyMetadata("test3 default text"));        
    }  

public class Test2 : Control
    {
        static Test2()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Test2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Test2)));
        }

        public FrameworkElement Test3Control
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(Test3ControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(Test3ControlProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Test3ControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Test3Control", typeof(FrameworkElement), 
            typeof(Test2), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public string Test
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(string), typeof(Test2), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata("test2 default text"));
    }

public partial class Test1 : UserControl
    {
        public Test1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Test
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(string), 
            typeof(Test1), new UIPropertyMetadata("test1 default text"));        
    }
```

XAML for usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Test1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:dummy="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication.Test"
             Name="ucThis">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type test:Test2}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type test:Test2}">
                        <GroupBox Header="Test2">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{TemplateBinding Test}"/>
                                <GroupBox Header="Test3">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Test3Control}"/>
                                </GroupBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GroupBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <test:Test2 Test="{Binding ElementName=ucThis,Path=Test}">
            <test:Test2.Test3Control>
                <test:Test3 Test="{Binding ElementName=ucThis,Path=Test}">
                    <test:Test3.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type test:Test3}">
                            <TextBox IsEnabled="False" Text="{TemplateBinding Test}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </test:Test3.Template>
                </test:Test3>
            </test:Test2.Test3Control>
        </test:Test2>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

... and XAML for main window (the guts of it, anyway):

```
<DockPanel>            
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="tbInput"/>    

        <Expander Header="Initially Visible" IsExpanded="True">
            <test:Test1 Test="{Binding ElementName=tbInput, Path=Text}" />
        </Expander>

        <Expander Header="Initially Collapsed" IsExpanded="False">
            <test:Test1 Test="{Binding ElementName=tbInput, Path=Text}" />
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>    
</DockPanel>
```

I would expect that whatever text is entered into the textbox ("tbInput") would be displayed in the Test2 and Test3 boxes - and indeed it is for both instances of Test2 but only for the Test3 that is initially visible. The Test3 that is initially collapsed always displays the default text, even if it is visible when the text is entered.

I've tried to investigate this using Snoop, but the issue corrects itself when I evaluate the relevant parts of the tree w/ Snoop so it hasn't been much help.

What is causing this behavior? How can I correct it? Where can I read more about it?

UPDATE:

By watching the output window I discovered this error message:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ucThis'. BindingExpression:Path=Test; DataItem=null; target element is 'Dummy3' (Name=''); target property is 'Test' (type 'String')`

By handling the loaded and initialized events on these controls I can see that this error occurs after Dummy1 and Dummy2 have loaded at startup. Dummy 3 doesn't load until it is made visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that, since the template has not been applied for the collapsed `Test3` instance, it has not been inserted into the visual tree.  It is therefore not within the name scope of the outer `Test1` instance when the binding is created, and thus cannot resolve the name `ucThis` specified for `ElementName`.

You can deal with this by adding `Test3Control` to the logical tree of `Test2`.  Try modifying the dependency property definition as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Test3ControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Test3Control", typeof(FrameworkElement),
    typeof(Test2), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnTest3ControlPropertyChanged));

private static void OnTest3ControlPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var source = (Test2)d;

    var oldValue = e.OldValue as FrameworkElement;
    var newValue = e.NewValue as FrameworkElement;

    if (oldValue != null)
        source.RemoveLogicalChild(oldValue);

    if (newValue != null)
        source.AddLogicalChild(newValue);
}
```

In most cases when you add a new `UIElement`-based property to a control, you will want to ensure it gets added to the logical tree.  This does not happen automatically.  For that matter, it does not get added to the visual tree automatically either.  In this case it is only loaded into the visual tree because it is explicitly inserted into the template.

Take a look at the internals of WPF's core controls, like `Decorator` (from which `Border` derives) and its `Child` property to see what kind of plumbing may be required when defining new control types.

Also note how many "child control" properties are **not** dependency properties.  It's easy to run into problems with `Visual`-based dependency properties, particularly when you attempt to change them via setters or animate them.  I find it's best to discourage developers from misusing the properties and creating headaches for themselves by simply exposing child controls as regular CLR properties.

Comment: Thank you so much. That resolved the issue.

Thanks also for your advice re: child controls as dependency properties. I will consider that closely.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about *your* specific problem, but I'd move the Test2's implicit style definition to the Generic.xaml module which has to be in the "Themes" folder. The framework will scan automatically that file to look for implicit styles.

Comment: Is that a stylistic choice? The framework will also scan the page for implicit styles and it's clear the style is being applied - otherwise Test2 would be invisible, no?